# Can one process corrupt another process by IPC?

Tags: memory, process, ipc

From my research I understand that if two processes communicate through shared memory then if the shared segment gets damaged, both processes will most likely be affected.

What I would like to know is whether or not a damaged process has the ability to corrupt a healthy process memory just by passing a bad file descriptor or sending a corrupted message through IPC methods like unix sockets or dbus. In case it matters, I am asking about corruption due to programming errors and not purposeful exploitation.

I apologize if my question is too broad and I presume that the answer will be obvious to an experienced programmer, however this is something that has been bugging me for some time and it is very hard to find a satisfying answer on the web.

Comment: It all depends on the IPC used and how it is being processed by the receiving side.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely yes.
If the receiving process is assumes a certain memory layout and you corrupt it, it can easily behave wrong.